# Debugging Kext with Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, kernel-extension, xnu

It would be great to have my lldb debugger run under xcode - it works fine for user-space applications, but what about Kext.

in userspace, if you may use the debugger in one of the following scenarios:

1. start new process from your project.
2. wait for process with specific name to come up.
3. connect to an existing process (according to IP).

All of these options doesn't require lldb command line to initiate and therefore may be easily triggered from xcode configuration charts.

However, in kernel extension debugging, it's an whole different story, since one must trigger `kdp <remote ip>` in order to connect the machine under debug. is it optional to do so from xcode ?

Alternatively, I'd like to hear about other gui wrappers for lldb that are capable for this task.

thanks

Comment: See [Apple1](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptDebugger/debug_tutorial.html), [Apple2](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WritingDeviceDriver/DebuggingDrivers/DebuggingDrivers.html) and [this oldish answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025906/developing-and-debugging-kext-on-mac).

Comment: those are nice articles, but non of them explain if the option to use xcode for debugging kext is possible

Comment: I do not understand. Several kdp options and flags are explained in detail, also remote-kdp.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of doing this from within Xcode. As you say you would need to run a custom script on debugger launch. There's certainly no UI for this in Xcode. You could try filing a feature request radar, but don't get your hopes up.

Comment: @pmdj, perhaps do you know other gui wrappers for lldb that enable kdp ?

Comment: @osxUser I'm afraid I do not. And yes, kernel debugging on Mac is a pain in the rear.